# Azure AD B2C Validation Profile for non-SelfAsserted Technical profiles

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

From testing, it appears Validation Technical Profiles are only used when added to SelfAssserted Technical Profiles

E.g the following:

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="ExternalIDP">
      <DisplayName>Some External IdP</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <Metadata>
        <!-- ... -->
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- ... -->
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="FETCH-MORE-CLAIMS" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

does not appear to call the `FETCH-MORE-CLAIMS` profile after authenticating to the external identity provider.

Is this correct, and if so, is there another way to always force a second technical profile to be called whenever a particular technical profile is called?

Comment: One possible way would be to set an output claim that indicates that was done, and then have an orchestration step after that with a condition on that claim, which then runs your TP as a claims exchange.

Comment: Hi @juunas You should add the above comment as answer. :)

Comment: If you say so Chris ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way would be to set an output claim that indicates that was done, and then have an orchestration step after that with a condition on that claim, which then runs your TP as a claims exchange.

So an output claim like:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="idp" DefaultValue="ThisIdp" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
```

You'd need to define that claim if it isn't already defined, or you can use another one you already have.

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false"> 
      <Value>idp</Value>
      <Value>ThisIdp</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="FetchMoreClaimsExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="FETCH-MORE-CLAIMS" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

This orchestration step is skipped if idp != ThisIdp, so it would only run if your external idp was used.

Comment: Hi @juunas, this in fact how it is implemented now :)  It works but I was just wondering if there was another way, because it still means replicating the two orchestration steps each time the identity provider is needed.

Comment: Hey juunas: can you shed some light here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58773626/114029