# How to pass and validate the signInEmail claim during External IDP login using Azure B2C custom policy?

Tags: email, azure-ad-b2c, idp, validation-technical-profile, orchestration-step

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57891462/114029).

What we'd like to do is: at the moment the user clicks the button like `Facebook` OR `Microsoft account` OR `Corporate AD` in the Sign in page, call a validation technical profile to validate the `email` address the user is using to sign in.

I tried adding an `OrchestrationStep` like this:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" 
  Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" 
      ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>idp</Value>
      <Value>CorporateAD</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="FetchMoreClaimsExchange" 
      TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-ValidateSignInEmail" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

This is actually calling `REST-ValidateSignInEmail` because I see an error returned in the URL like this:

> https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C%3a++is+disabled.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+bce3fd82-1111-4f17-ad99-ef7770ed8dda%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2019-11-08+20%3a34%3a51Z%0d%0a&state=7b7c70e7-7a77-77d7-7d7e-7dd0e7b707e7

The message `is+disabled` is coming from the REST API I put together but this obviously tells me that the email\signInEmail claim it expects as a parameter is not being sent\passed.

This is the Technical Profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-ValidateSignInEmail">
    <DisplayName>Validate Email</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" 
            Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
       <Item Key="ServiceUrl">{Settings:AzureAppServiceUrl}/api/B2C/ValidateSignInEmail</Item>
       <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
       <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" 
              PartnerClaimType="UserEmail" />
        </InputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Can you shed some light on how to approach this?

Comment: How have you defined the REST technical profile?

Comment: @juunas I'm going to add the technical profile in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally after I post the question I keep fiddling with the code.

Got it working like this:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-ValidateSignInEmail">
    <DisplayName>Validate Email</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" 
            Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
       <Item Key="ServiceUrl">{Settings:AzureAppServiceUrl}/api/B2C/ValidateSignInEmail</Item>
       <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
       <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" 
              PartnerClaimType="UserEmail" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" 
              PartnerClaimType="UserEmail" />
        </InputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Note that I added a new `InputClaim` with `ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"`. `email` is the claim value that is passed when using an external IDP.

This [sample policy](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/rest-api/blob/master/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml) showed me that I could add the `OrchestrationStep` right before the `JwtIssuer` one. We can also have it without any preconditions like this:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="7" 
   Type="ClaimsExchange">
   <ClaimsExchanges>
     <ClaimsExchange Id="REST-ValidateSignInEmail" 
       TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-ValidateSignInEmail" />
   </ClaimsExchanges>
 </OrchestrationStep>
```

Doing so it'll get called for all IDPs.

---

[Azure Active Directory B2C: Custom CIAM User Journeys](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples)