# How to display error returned from custom REST API endpoint in a subsequent orchestration step?

Tags: error-handling, azure-ad-b2c, orchestration-step, validation-technical-profile

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58773626/114029)... the REST API endpoint is validating the external IDP email and is correclty returning an error back in the case the email is not valid.

```cs
return Content(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new CustomResponseContent
{
    Version = "1.0.0",
    Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict,
    UserMessage = message
});
```

Now I'd like to detect this error and use it in a subsequent `OrchestrationStep` like this:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" 
  Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="REST-ValidateSignInEmail" 
      TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-ValidateSignInEmail" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<!-- Taken from here: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/creating-an-error-page-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-flow-fb2692a3b50f -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" 
  Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" 
      ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>extension_Flag</Value>
      <Value>False</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedRegError" 
      TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-RegError" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

If step **`3`** returns a conflict, I'd like to show the error message in step **`4`** using the custom error page implemented as described [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/creating-an-error-page-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-flow-fb2692a3b50f).

I see that step **`4`** executes based on `extension_Flag`.

Is there any way I could retrieve and store the result from `REST-ValidateSignInEmail` and use it in the flag for step **`4`**?

Note: when the user journey finishes executing I see the following AADB2C error in the URL. It comes from the REST API endpoint error (409 - Conflict)...

> https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C%3a+user%40gmail.com+is+not+valid.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%7a+7777f77-7afd-7777-a777-7c77b7e77b7b%0d%0aTimestamp%7a+2019-11-09+14%3a40%3a57Z%0d%0a&state=7777c77a-77ad-414a-84df-3c131ed81ba7

The `error_description` message is what I'd like to pass to step **`4`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this in a different way... instead of returning a Conflict [409] status, I changed the REST endpoint to return an `OutputClaim` like this:

```xml
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isEnabled" 
        PartnerClaimType="IsEnabled" DefaultValue="false"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="errorMessage" 
        PartnerClaimType="ErrorMessage"/>
</OutputClaims>
```

This way I have a claim to check on step **`4`**. Note that I also return an `errorMessage` from the endpoint. This error message will be later passed to `SelfAsserted-RegError` Technical Profile.

Depending on the validation done in the back-end, `extension_isEnabled` will get **True** or **False**.

On step **`4`** we check `extension_isEnabled`:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" 
                   Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" 
                      ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>extension_isEnabled</Value>
            <Value>True</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
         <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedRegError" 
                         TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-RegError" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Step **`4`** will only be executed when `extension_isEnabled` is **false**. If it is **true** we `SkipThisOrchestrationStep` and the `SelfAsserted-RegError` Technical Profile won't be called at all. The `UserJourney` flow continues as expected.