# B2C: Localization for messages originating from REST API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am currently implementing [this example](https://github.com/mninawa/aadb2c-verification-link) to use an rest API during the user registration.

The basic idea is that the API throws an 409 Conflict error to interrupt the registration.

```cs
// Can I return a special "StringId" or something here for localization?
return new ConflictObjectResult(new B2CResponseModel($"A verification email sent to you. Please open your mail box and click on the link. If you didn't receive the email, please click on the 'Send verification email' button.", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
```

I want to show the user a message that is localized to their current language. I would prefer to do the localization within the custom policies, but I would also accept a solution within the API (would need to get the User Language for this).

Is there a way to do this localization? Like returning a `StringId` via API and using this within the policy?

I am also considering not returning an error from the API, to show the [message in a new screen](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/creating-an-error-page-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-flow-fb2692a3b50f) instead (like [How to display error returned from custom REST API endpoint in a subsequent orchestration step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774940/how-to-display-error-returned-from-custom-rest-api-endpoint-in-a-subsequent-orch)). However, localization options for this elude me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788906/localised-message-for-restapi-error-response-in-b2c-custom-policy)

See the answer by **Jas Suri**. Pass the localisation parameter to API and return the localised message or can return an error code and based on that display translated message using policy itself.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody is looking for a way to send the user's locale to the REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SendVerificationEmail">
          <DisplayName>Sign-Up send link</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://xxxx</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userLanguage" DefaultValue="{Culture:LanguageName}" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="policyId" PartnerClaimType="policy" DefaultValue="{Policy:PolicyId}" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="{OIDC:scope}" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="clientId" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" />
          </InputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```